# Select Sort array comparisons

Tags: arrays, function, sorting, select

Hi Users of Stack Overflow,

I am trying to find out how to work out how many array comparisons take place within a method. The arrayMaxPos function takes n-1 comparisons to find the maximum element in the array of size n.

I am just looking to get my head around this.

```
public static void SelectSort(int [] a, int n)
  {
    for (int i = n; i> 1; i--)
    {
      int maxPos = arrayMaxPos(a, i);
      swop(a, maxPos, i-1);
    }
  }
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: by the way have you checked your - does this method real works to sort an array - u r running a loop from i=n to i>1 .

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be ((N-1)^2)/2 comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

you could have analysed that of your own by either debugging your code or by simply putting print statements in betweeen.
and for your answer - selection sort take **n(n − 1) / 2** to sort an array

Comment: Ah right thanks, what if I am only provided with the code and have no access to be able to debug it. Is there a way I can work it out by just using my head?

Comment: @user1028145: [This section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Analysis) on the Wikipedia page may help.

Comment: @user1028145 what do you mean by no access to be able to debug it?? if you cant debug that using any IDE then analyse it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop is taking n-1 iterations.
Your inner loop (arrayMaxPos(...)) is taking from n to 1, therefore n/2.

So as some other answers already explained: **n(n-1)/2**